# How to make pandas/core/generic/pct_change to return a positive value when changing from a negative to a positive value

Tags: python, pandas

```
ipdb> df["input"]
datetime
2011-01-01    2.577163
2011-01-02    0.579833
2011-01-03   -0.191187
2011-01-04    0.430754

ipdb> df["input"].pct_change()
datetime
2011-01-01         NaN
2011-01-02   -0.775011
2011-01-03   -1.329728
2011-01-04   -3.253050
```

I want the value of `2011-01-04   -3.253050` to be 3.253050. Is there an option in pct_change() function that would allow this? Otherwise, what would be an efficient way to do this?

Essentially for each pct_change calculation, I want to multiply by -1 if the previous value < 0 and the current value is > 0. Ideally I want a way that doesn't use a for loop in python but that is all that comes to mind now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your condition out and multiply by -1 wherever it's met:

```
>>> p = df["input"].pct_change()
>>> p
datetime
2011-01-01         NaN
2011-01-02   -0.775011
2011-01-03   -1.329728
2011-01-04   -3.253051
Name: input, dtype: float64
>>> p.loc[(df["input"].shift() < 0) & (df["input"] > 0)] *= -1
>>> p
datetime
2011-01-01         NaN
2011-01-02   -0.775011
2011-01-03   -1.329728
2011-01-04    3.253051
Name: input, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I know this has been asked and answered a loooong time ago. But I was getting into kinda the same problem. My question is, what do you do if the previous value is -1.2 and the next value is -1 ...  pct_change will still have it be a minus value, but the increase should be completely positive...