# Handling negative values in pct_changes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this df_is_processed dataframe which contain ticker (stock code), year, and net profit. I would like to do percentage change on the netprofit grouped by ticker and year.

| Ticker | Year | Net Income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 2005 | 151 |
| AAPL | 2004 | -50 |
| MSFT | 2005 | 80 |
| MSFT | 2004 | 100 |

To do that is actually straightforward forward with the help of `pct_change` function on pandas.

```
df_is_processed['Delta Net Income'] = df_is_processed.sort_values('Year').groupby(['Ticker'])['Net Income'].pct_change()
```

However i run into some issue when negative value are encountered, which can be seen on AAPL ticker.

| Ticker | Year | Net Income | Delta Net Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 2005 | 151 | -4.02 |
| AAPL | 2004 | -50 | NaN |
| MSFT | 2005 | 80 | -0.20 |
| MSFT | 2004 | 100 | NaN |

The expected outcome is AAPL has positive delta net income at 2005.

| Ticker | Year | Net Income | Delta Net Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 2005 | 151 | 4.02 |
| AAPL | 2004 | -50 | NaN |
| MSFT | 2005 | 80 | -0.20 |
| MSFT | 2004 | 100 | NaN |

I have tried this post but it does not work and doesn’t have group by option.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362884/how-to-make-pandas-core-generic-pct-change-to-return-a-positive-value-when-chang][1]

Pandas version : 1.2.2 
Python version : 3.7.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### **`groupby`** + **`shift`**

```
s = df.sort_values('Year').groupby('Ticker')['Net Income'].shift()
df['Delta Net Income'] = df['Net Income'].sub(s).div(s.abs())
```

#### Explanation

`Sort` the dataframe on `Year` then `group` the dataframe by `Ticker` and `shift` the column `Net Income` one unit downwards.

```
>>> s

1      NaN
3      NaN
0    -50.0
2    100.0
Name: Net Income, dtype: float64
```

Subtract the shifted column `s` from `Net Income` to get the difference.

```
>>> df['Net Income'].sub(s)

0    201.0
1      NaN
2    -20.0
3      NaN
Name: Net Income, dtype: float64
```

Divide the above difference by the magnitude of previous value to calculate the percent change.

```
>>> df['Net Income'].sub(s).div(s.abs())

0    4.02
1     NaN
2   -0.20
3     NaN
Name: Net Income, dtype: float64
```

#### Result

```
>>> df

  Ticker  Year  Net Income  Delta Net Income
0   AAPL  2005         151              4.02
1   AAPL  2004         -50               NaN
2   MSFT  2005          80             -0.20
3   MSFT  2004         100               NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead of pct_change():

```
>>> df['net_income_delta'] = -((df['net_income'].shift(1) - df['net_income']) / np.abs(df['net_income'].shift(1)) * 100)

>>> df[['ticker', 'net_income_delta']].groupby('ticker').sum()
```

Inspired by this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716767/how-to-calculate-the-percentage-of-increase-decrease-with-negative-numbers/716770

Comment: Hi i've tried your answer but instead i got 160.64257. Anyhow answer from Shubham is working tho, so thanks for the effort.